# A norm generated by the quadratic form of T implies T is an isomorphism.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, quadratic-forms, duality-theorems, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space. Let $T:\mathcal{H}  \to \mathcal{H}'$ be bounded and linear with the following unique continuation property:

$\langle Tx,x \rangle_{\mathcal{H}',\mathcal{H}} =0 \implies x=0$

Then this quadratic form defines a norm on $\mathcal{H}$. Let $F$ be the completion of $\mathcal{H}$ with respect to this new norm. Then $T$ is an isomorphism from $F \to F'$.

This is clear to me until the final sentence. How do we even know that $T$ is defined on $F$. I can see that $T$ should be one-to-one with dense range, but that is it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $H$ is a real Hilbert space. **Suppose $T$ self-adjoint**.
Suppose $\langle Tx,x\rangle \ge0$ for all $x$. Then
$$
\|x\|_T:= \sqrt{\langle Tx,x\rangle}
$$
defines the new norm, which is induced by the new  inner product
$$
( x,y)_T:=\langle Tx,x\rangle.
$$

Let us show that $T$ is continuous from $(H,\|\cdot\|_T)$ to its dual space $(H,\|\cdot\|_T)'$. 
Let me denote the norm in the dual space by $\|\cdot\|_{T'}$. Take $x\in H$, then
$$
\|Tx\|_{T'}=\sup_{y: \|y\|_T\le 1} (Tx)(y) 
= \sup_{y: \|y\|_T\le 1} \langle Tx,y\rangle 
= \sup_{y: \|y\|_T\le 1} (x,y)_T =\|x\|_T.
$$
Hence $T$ is bounded with respect to the new norm.
As $H$ is dense in $F$ with respect to the new norm by construction, we can uniquely extend $T$ to a linear and continuous operator from $F$ to $(H,\|\cdot\|_T)'$. The extension has the same norm, thus $T:F\to (H,\|\cdot\|_T)'$ is an isometry.

Since $F$ is the completion of $(H,\|\cdot\|_T)$ it follows that $F'$ and $(H,\|\cdot\|_T)'$ are isometric isomorph: The restriction of a functional $f\in F'$ is in $(H,\|\cdot\|_T)'$, whereas the unique extension of $h\in (H,\|\cdot\|_T)'$ is in $F'$. The restriction and extension operations preserve norms.

Maybe the answer is overly complicated and verbose. 
The idea behind everything is that
$T$ can be regarded as isometric isomorphism between $F$ and $F'$. In fact, $T$ is the Riesz isomorphism of the (Hilbert!) space $F$.

---

The operator $T$ is not an isometry if $T$ is not supposed to be self-adjoint. Take $H=\mathbb R^2$ and 
$$
T=\pmatrix{1 & 10 \\ -10 & 1}.
$$
Then $x^TTx=\|x\|_2^2$ and $\|x\|_T=\|x\|_2$. Then the operator norm of $T$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ and $\|\cdot\|_T$ coincide. But $\|T\|_2\ne 1$ obviously.

Comment: Thanks. So just to clarify, T is not the isomorphism, but rather the unique extension to F is?

Comment: Yes, the extension of $T$ to $F$ is the isomorphism.

Comment: It is not clear to me that $(x,y)_T = \langle Tx,y \rangle$ is an inner product. Wouldn't that require $T$ to be self-adjoint?

Comment: Thanks for your help. This was still very enlightening and I'll keep thinking about it. It looks like it only affects the boundedness of $T$ in the new norm, so maybe there is a way around that.

Comment: @Walton Added an example that shows the claim is not true for not self-adjoint $T$.